# How to Change the color of an active link tag

Tags: jquery, css

Following is the code for link tab,

**HTML**

```
<div class="sortLinks right">
    <label>Sort by</label>
    <a onclick="javascript:SortOrder('DATE')" href="#">Date Modified</a>
    <span class="sort_sep">&nbsp;</span>
    <a onclick="javascript:SortOrder('ALPHA')" href="#">Alphabetical</a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
a:focus
{
    color:Blue;    
}
```

**JQuery**

```
function SortOrder(order) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        url: "@Url.Action("SecondarySkillDetails", "SkillLifeCycle")",
        data: { primarySkillID: $("#ddlPrimarySkills").val(), sortorder: order },
        success: function (data) {
            $("#content").html(data);
        },
        error: function (xhr, textStatus, error) {
           alert (error);
        }
    });
}
```

I want to highlight the active link in blue color.here while selecting a link it's highlighted in blue color and once when I click outside it becomes black color again.How can i avoid this?

Comment: You Can Use this a:visited{} to highlight the activelink

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed it a little more that the others but here is a working example.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/25fDu/3/)

First I updated the click logic to use an on then used the on to add the class `active` to the active selection.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.sortLinks').on('click','a',function() {
        $('.sortLinks a').removeClass("active");
        var clazz = $(this).attr('class');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        SortOrder(clazz);
    });
});
```

Note in example I commented out you ajax call (as it wouldn't work in the fiddle)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do it solely using HTML and CSS, you can use hidden radio buttons to achieve this.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GtChc/1/)

HTML

```
<label class="sort" onchange="alert('Sorting by: date')">
    <input type="radio" name="sort" value="date" checked />
    <span>Date Modified</span>
</label>
```

CSS

```
.sort > input[type=radio] {
    display: none;   
}

.sort {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.sort > input[type=radio]:checked + span {
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: Clever I like it, although technically `alert();` is javascript

Comment: Ah yeah, I merely added it as a pointer to how one could extend it if additional javascript would be needed (which I assume one want in order to do the actual sorting) :)

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
a {
color: #0077CC;
cursor: pointer;
text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
text-decoration: underline;
color: #0077CC !important;
}
a:visited {
color: #4A6B82;
}
a:active {
color: #6BAC28;
font-weight: bold;
text-decoration: underline;
}
```