# How to change the color of the active link in the menu

Tags: html, css

Here is the menu html code for the nav bar:

```
<nav>
        <div id="menu">
        <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html">Home Page</a></li>
            <li><a href="history.html">History</a></li>
            <li><a href="events.html">Events</a></li>
            <li><a href="inf.html">Information</a></li>
            <li><a href="photo.html">Photos</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="links.html">Useful Links</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

and here's the code for css :

```
 nav{
float: left;
margin-top: 15px;
}

nav ul {
list-style: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;

}

nav li {
display: inline-block;

}

nav a {
padding: 8px 0px;
margin-right:71px;
color: #ffffff;
display: block;
text-decoration: none;
text-transform: capitalize;
font-size: 13px;
}

nav a:hover {
color: #cccccc;
}
```

So for example, if I am currently looking at history page, the text "History" in the navbar will be red. How can I do such a thing?

@edit: As stated in a comment, I am trying to avoid jquery.

Comment: You have [tons of questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[css]+%22active+link%22+%22color%22) here on the same topic

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Change the color of an active link tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19766144/how-to-change-the-color-of-an-active-link-tag)

Comment: I am trying to avoid jquery since I am still a beginner with html and css, and when I searched for topics, they only consisted of jquery. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: See the first link please. I am sure you'll  find an answer to your query. To the right of the [search page](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=#) you will find **Advanced Search Tips**. I hope that feature help you in feature

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a great resource for beginners: [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/)

This page on that site contains the answer to your question: [CSS Text Formating](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_text.asp)

I don't mean to be vague, but your question is a little unclear.

Comment: Danny Pranoto got the right idea. Sorry for confusing :) Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

just add `active` class name in the active state link.

```
<li><a href="index.html">Home Page</a></li>
<li><a href="history.html">History</a></li>
<li><a class="active" href="events.html">Events</a></li>
<li><a href="inf.html">Information</a></li>
```

And in your CSS

```
nav a.active {
   color: red;
}
```

Comment: You may ask the op first to search the site for questions on same topic.

Comment: sorry, will do it next time... thanks for the suggestion :)

Comment: @DannyPranoto : There may be users who downvote an answer just for this reason. I am not the downvoter here anyway. :D

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use jQuery to add an `active` class to the anchor tag that corresponds with the page that you are on. Once that is done you can style it like this `a.active {color:red}`

If these are individual HTML pages you could also just manually apply the `active` class to the anchor tag for that page.

Answer (score 0):

The CSS attribute you are describing is a CSS selector.  Your CSS will be as follows, which will target all "active" hrefs in the div ID menu

```
#menu a:active {
   color: blue;
}
```